# What's an Alternative/Fix to $.post for Cross Domain for Unknown Amount of Domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cors, cross-domain

This could be a very amateur/bad approach to what really needs to be done, but I'm currently building a platform that can be embedded on clients' websites with a script tag. That script then allows a user to input some information and send it off to an email. One of the options on there is to see a certain person's social media. What I want to do is log the social button clicks to a MySQL database.

Currently my code for the social click is a `$.post` to `b.domain.com`. I'm getting the error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load due to access control checks.` This error goes away when I manually add each domain to the allow origin in .htaccess, but this would be very frustrating to have to add this for every domain a client wants to embed the script on. `*` can't be used because of `Allow Credentials` so I'm kind of stuck in my limited knowledge on this topic.

Any pointing in the right direction would be appreciated, and apologies if the question wasn't worded properly/with enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This error goes away when I manually add each domain to the allow origin in .htaccess, but this would be very frustrating to have to add this for every domain a client wants to embed the script on.
>   `*` can't be used because of `Allow Credentials`

So instead of sending `*` in the response you can have the value of the `Origin` request header essentially just echoed to the value of the 
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase ORIGIN (.*) ORIGIN=$1
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN}e"
```

That will allow requests from any origin even when the requests  include credentials.

Below is an alternative way to achieve the same effect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Origin} (.+)
RewriteRule . - [E=CORS_ORIGIN:%1]
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{CORS_ORIGIN}e env=CORS_ORIGIN
```